# VS 2013 Preview not works because MSVCR120.dll is missing

Tags: visual-studio-2013

[image: MSVCR120.dll is missing]

I can't start VS 2013 RC. And I Also can't uninstall VS 2013 RC too.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: may I know your version whether it is express edition rc

Answer (score 0):

MSVCR120.dll is actually a C++ Runtime DLLs If you installed using ISO then you need to search for a file which is related to c++ runtime.

If you don't got the file make a thread on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com) and put detail their. Someone from Visual studio team will help you their.

When I check the ISO of VWD 2013 RC I got a folder seen in setup folder that is vcRuntime....

Install all Those MSI. I hope it will fix your issue.